# Passing current_user to a form without using hidden fields (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently in my Rails app, I have users, swatches, and bottles.

A swatch belongs to a bottle and the user that submitted it.
A bottle does not belong to a user.

```
class Swatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :swatch, SwatchUploader
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bottle
end

class Bottle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swatches
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swatches
end
```

Currently, the user can upload new swatches for a bottle from the bottle's show page.

Here's the swatch controller:

```
class SwatchesController < ApplicationController
   def create
    @bottle = Bottle.find(params[:bottle_id])
    @user = current_user
    @swatch = @bottle.swatches.create(swatch_params)
    redirect_to bottle_path(@bottle)
  end

  private
    def swatch_params
      params.require(:swatch).permit(:swatch, :user_id, :bottle_id)
    end
end
```

HAML:

```
= form_for([@bottle, @bottle.swatches.build]) do |f|
    = f.label :swatch
    = f.file_field :swatch
    = f.submit
```

With this set up, the form won't work unless I pass the current user's ID as a hidden field. But I know that is bad practice and would like to avoid that.

So my question is: **How do I pass both the `bottle_id` and current user's `user_id` through the controllers?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you need to pass `current_user` through the form?  In your controller, if you want to set `user_id` to the `current_user` id, just do that as such:

app/models/swatch.rb

```
class Swatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :swatch, SwatchUploader
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bottle

  def set_user!(user)
    self.user_id = user.id

    self.save!
  end
end
```

app/controllers/swatches_controller.rb

```
class SwatchesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @bottle = Bottle.find(params[:bottle_id])

    @user = current_user

    @swatch = @bottle.swatches.new(swatch_params)
    @swatch.set_user!(current_user)

    redirect_to bottle_path(@bottle)
  end

  private

  def swatch_params
    params.require(:swatch).permit(:swatch, :bottle_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

can't you just use current_user for the user?, for the bottle_id, I guess the best would be to have the bottle in the address, since you are creating a swatch for a bottle, you url could be something like:

```
/bottles/<id of bottle>/swatches
```

your route should be

```
post "/bottles/:bottle_id/swatches", to: 'swatches#create'
```

then, on your controller SwatchesController, you can do

```
def create
  bottle = Bottle.find(params[:bottle_id])
  swatch = current_user.swatches.create params[:swatch].merge(bottle: bottle)
  if swatch.new_record?
    #something if not saved
  else
    #something if saved
  end
end
```